# Failed to establish connection between 1 Organisation peer and channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I have created a Solo config Fabric network with 2 Organisation peers connected to single channel on launching the network My 1st Organisation peer is sucessfully getting connected to channel but for 2nd organisation peer it says:

`Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to org2-peer1.org2.com:8051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8051: connect: connection refused"`

Comment: Please add your config file here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all docker containers are up and running.

```
docker ps
```